# converge in fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-series

Good day, Im studyng about convergence in fourier series, theorem 8.14. I dont understand when Rudin says: the two integrals tends to zero by 74. Where is used the hypothesis about bounded?[image]

[image]

Comment: For (73), you really only need that $f$ is absolutely square integrable. And boundedness gives you that. Boundedness is overkill, unless you're using the Riemann integral. Every Riemann integrable function must be bounded.

Comment: I must take the coefficients $C_n$ as sinNt and cosNt?

Comment: The function $f$ in your original statement may first be $g(t)\cos(t/2)$, and then can be $g(t)\sin(t/2)$. That's how you conclude that the last two integrals in your post vanish as $N\rightarrow\infty$. So, first $c_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left[g(t)\cos(t/2)\right]\sin Ntdt$.

Comment: but for these first integral g(t)cos(t/2) the coefficients must write in terms of $exp(inx)$?

Comment: @mathspika $\int g(t)\cos(t/2) \sin Nt\ dt$ is the imaginary part of $\int g(t)\cos(t/2) e^{iNt}\ dt$ (assuming $g$ is real-valued). If the latter converges to $0$ as $N \to \infty$, then so does the former.

Comment: who is $\phi _n$ associated to g(t)cos(t/2)?

Comment: @mathspika : $c_n = \int g(t)\cos(t/2) \sin Ntdt$ and $\phi_n = \sin Nt$. Then do the same for $c_n = \int g(t)\cos(t/2) \cos Ndt$ and $\phi_n = \cos Nt$. The functions $\sin Nt$ are mutually orthogonal. So are the functions $\cos Nt$. In fact, all of these are mutually orthogonal.